# Write to Firebase Storage with JavaScript gives "Cross-Origin Request Blocked"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have made a web app which includes a form with two fields and what I want to happen is when I click the button, my data should be written to Firebase. So I made an onclick function which writes to Firebase, the function is called but it doesn't write to Firebase. I get this error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
>   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/storymap-da000.appspot.com/o?name=11-2-2018-0-6-27.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]

My vanilla JavaScript code:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "XXX",
    authDomain: "XXX",
    databaseURL: "XXX",
    projectId: "XXX",
    storageBucket: "XXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXX"
  };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);

window.addEventListener('load', function() {

const fileButton = document.getElementById("fileButton");
const up = document.getElementById("up")


});


fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(image_name);
               storageRef.put(file)

});

up.onclick=function(){

var lat = new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("lat")
var lng = new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("lng")
var title = document.getElementById("title").value
var story = document.getElementById("story").value


var database = firebase.firestore()

database.collection("Stories").add({
title:title,
story:story,
lat: lat,
lng:lng,
url:image_name});}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you move your firebase config and init inside of your load? I have a feeling it is losing reference to the app.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to register your domain in your firebase app

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: In your firebase console on Auth page on sign-in method page will be "Add domain" button.
You need to add your trusted domain in order to make Cross domain requests

Comment: I don't this is the issue. Because, first of all, If I put the firebase outside the function is write to firebase...secondly I use it locally